# Get chrome.topSites and recently closed tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-history

I am developing chrome extension which will replace the new tab UI
I am able to retrieve the installed app info.
however I am not able to retrieve the most visited and recently closed tab info..

My manifest.json

```
{
 "name": "Cloud Tab",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "New Tab with cloud UI.",
"background_page": "background.html",
"permissions": [ "tabs","management","topSites",
    "chrome://favicon/"],

"chrome_url_overrides": {
"newtab": "CloudTab.html"
}
}
```

My CloudTab.html page's script tag contains

```
 chrome.topSites.get(function(info){
   for(var i=0;i<info.length;i++) {alert(info[i].url);}
  });
```

but I get error:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined**

I have referred the Google's API for this but no luck.
I'm running Chrome's version 13.0.782.
Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: AFAIK `alert` will not work, instead use `console.log`

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this question like I just did, here are the Chrome extension API's for `topSites`: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/topSites and `sessions.getRecentlyClosed`: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/sessions#method-getRecentlyClosed

Answer (score 2):

I tried this way and it's working in **chrome 37**

#### popup.js

```
function onAnchorClick(event) {
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: event.srcElement.href });
  return false;
}

function buildPopupDom(mostVisitedURLs) {
  var popupDiv = document.getElementById('mostVisited_div');
  var ol = popupDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('ol'));

  for (var i = 0; i < mostVisitedURLs.length; i++) {
    var li = ol.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    var a = li.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
    a.href = mostVisitedURLs[i].url;
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mostVisitedURLs[i].title));
    a.addEventListener('click', onAnchorClick);
  }
}
chrome.topSites.get(buildPopupDom);
```

#### popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <h2>Most visited links</h2>
    <div id="mostVisited_div"></div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### manifest.json

<strike>"chrome_url_overrides": {
"newtab": "CloudTab.html"
}</strike>

```
"permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "topSites",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
  ],            
"browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon_32.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
 "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["popup.js"]
 }]
```

Answer (score 1):

To use this API, your Chrome's version must be greater than or equal to 19.
See Google Chrome extensions' What's New in Extensions page:[http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/whats_new.html#19](https://web.archive.org/web/20120805034220/http://code.google.com:80/chrome/extensions/whats_new.html#19)

Answer (score 0):

You can track closed tabs with listener of [onRemoved](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onRemoved) event in the background page and request the info from it with some [messages](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html).

Comment: `tabs.onRemoved` isn't reliable, or at least it's usage isn't sufficient, because it gets called even for some invisible tabs, that cannot be differentiated from normal tabs. Moreover, in order to track Recently Closed tabs properly, you need to handle `tabs.onUpdated`, which is also not reliable :( http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109557

Answer (score 0):

The majority of Chrome API methods are asynchronous. So what you would need to do is pass in a callback function.

```
getTopSites: function(callbackfunc) {
    chrome.topSites.get (function(url_list) {
        for(var i=0;i<url_list.length;i++) {callbackfunc(url_list[i]);}
    });
}
```

You can then invoke it with a call back function like so:

```
getTopSites(function(url){alert(url);});
```

Excuse any syntax errors I made above..